# Getting ReSharper to replace multiple instances of a highlighted expression during Extract Method

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Can anybody please tell me how to get ReSharper to replace multiple instances (instead of just one) of a highlighted expression when using Extract Method ? I swear I've gotten it to do it before (just like Eclipse does in its Extract Method refactoring), but I'm unable to do it on the latest installation, 5.1. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new [structural search and replace](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/) support might allow you to do that.  Extract one instance to a method then replace other instances of that pattern with calls to the method.

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered "Find similar code" about a minute after I wrote that.  Good tip though.